# an inequality involving the zeta function and its derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

We know that it can be proved easily that $(s-1)\zeta(s) = s - s(s-1)\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{x\}}{x^{s+1}}dx$.

I am trying to use this to prove that $\zeta(s) + (s-1)\zeta'(s) > 1 - (2s-1)\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}}dt$.

It is clear that we have to differentiate the first expression, but how do I get the inequality? I am just missing it somehow.
Any pointers? Thanks

Comment: Simply differentiate the first expression and consider the sign of $s(s-1)\int_1^\infty \{x\} x^{-s-1}\log (x) dx$ depending on $s > 1$ or $s\in (0,1)$

Comment: What range do you want for $s$? As it stands you need real numbers to make sense of that inequality

Comment: oops. yes yes. s > 1.

Answer (score 0):

If $s>1$ differentiating your equality gives $$\zeta (s)+(s-1)\zeta '(s)=1-(2s-1)\int _1^\infty \frac {\{ t\} dt}{t^{s}}-\underbrace {s(s-1)}_{>0}\underbrace {\frac {d}{ds}\int _1^\infty \frac {\{ t\} dt}{t^{s}}}_{=:X}$$
so we're done if $X<0$.  But this is true because $$X=-\underbrace {\int _1^\infty \frac {\{ t\} \log tdt}{t^{s+1}}}_{>0}$$

Comment: yes yes, i undetsood this later while thinking myself. thanks anyway.